# Print out localized date with timezone in Java

Tags: java, date, timezone, java-time, datetimeformatter

I want to create a localized version of the current date without time, but with the user's time zone, in Java.

java.time.format.FormatStyle has the values - FULL:

```
Full text style, with the most detail. For example, the format might be 'Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD' or '3:30:42pm PST'.
```

and LONG.

```
Long text style, with lots of detail. For example, the format might be 'January 12, 1952'.
```

I basically want a mix of both - I just want to display the localized long date, like: January 12, 1952 - but aditionally, I want to add the time zone of this date,
January 12, 1952 PST or January 12, 1952 MEZ and so on.

I tried:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = zonedDateTime(instant, timezoneId);
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(userLocale);
String localizedDate = dateTime.format( dateFormatter.withZone(timezoneId));
```

But this did not add the timezone to the date. When I also print out the time, it works, but that's not what I want here in this case.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

The OP has mentioned that he wants to use a locale-specific pattern but output in English. For this, [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#getLocalizedDateTimePattern-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.format.FormatStyle-java.time.chrono.Chronology-java.util.Locale-) can be used to get the locale-specific pattern and then the same can be used in the `DateTimeFormatter` with `Locale.ENGLISH`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId timezoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        Locale userLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("fr");
        String pattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.LONG, null,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, userLocale);
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(instant.atZone(timezoneId).format(dtf) + " "
                + timezoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18 January 2021 PT
```

**For testing:** Change the value of `userLocale` to `Locale.US` in the above code and the output will change as follows:

```
January 18, 2021 PT
```

---

## Original answer

Please note the following [comment from Meno Hochschild, the Author of Time4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773961/print-out-localized-date-with-timezone-in-java/65774099#comment116306712_65774099) regarding the original answer:

*A style-based version (your before-part) and a pattern-based version (your since-part) are not equivalent for any locale.*

### Before Java-10:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("fr");
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendLocalized(FormatStyle.LONG, null)
                                            .appendLiteral(", ")
                                            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)                                            
                                            .toFormatter(locale);                                               
                                        
        String strLocalizedDate = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
        System.out.println(strLocalizedDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18 janvier 2021, PST
```

### Since Java-10:

You can use [`DateTimeFormatter#localizedBy​(Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#localizedBy(java.util.Locale)) as shown below:

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("fr");
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM uuuu, z")
                                                            .localizedBy(locale);

        String strLocalizedDate = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
        System.out.println(strLocalizedDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18 janvier 2021, PST
```

Comment: Actually, I would like to use the formatting of the given locale - so the order of year, month, date, according to the locale - your version uses a static Date pattern.
For now, I am using:
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(userLocale);
String myDate = instant.atZone(timezoneId).format( dateFormatter) + " " +  timezoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, userLocale);
This almost works, but it does ALSO use the name of the month localized in the given locale - instead of staying in English.

Comment: A style-based version (your before-part) and a pattern-based version (your since-part) are not equivalent for any locale.

Comment: @MarcusBiel - I've posted an update based on your clarification. I hope, it fulfils your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.